# JQuery Ajax Post to C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm trying to retrieve JSON Object on C# here is my JavasSciprt post but I'm unable to hande it on codebehind, thanks!

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "facebook/addfriends.aspx",
    data: { "data": response.data },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        location = '/facebook/login?URL=' + ReturnURL + '&UID=' + response.authResponse.userID + '&TK=' + response.authResponse.accessToken + '';
    }
});
```

I've tried to retrieve data like:

```
Request.Form["data"]
Request["data"]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an example from [Encosia.com](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) (I added a form parameter). You don't need to access `Page.Form` - you can use method parameters instead.

Codebehind

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate(string someParameter)
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
  $("#Result").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
      data: {someParameter: "some value"},
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not trying to get data from C# to Javascipt I'm trying to post data from JavaScript to C#

Comment: Yes but that doesn't contain a data holder on codebehind, I think the WebMethod keyword does the job?

Comment: Did you see the `someParameter` method parameter? That's your post data.

Comment: Thanks this is worked but I get error like response.data is not a JSon object

Comment: This isn't very informative. A bunch of code with no explanation.

Comment: Follow the Ecosia link for all of the nitty gritty information.

Comment: The part of code no need stringify data object helps me solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did and it worked for me:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "facebook/addfriends.aspx",
    data: "data=" + response.data + "&data1=anyothervaluelikethis",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        location = '/facebook/login?URL=' + ReturnURL + '&UID=' + response.authResponse.userID + '&TK=' + response.authResponse.accessToken + '';
    }
});
```

These two lines are modified

```
 data: "data=" + response.data + "&data1=anyothervaluelikethis",
 contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
```

Answer (score 2):

The codebehind C# method signature should look something like:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "MyMethod", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Object MyMethod(Object data){
 // your code
}
```

where Object can be any serializable class