# How can i call c# functions from JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have C# page with 2 functions - 1 to get data from my MSSQL database, and the second one to insert data into it.

I want to know how to use AJAX (or any other way?) to call this functions from JS file.
For one of the functions i only need to get data back, for the other one i need to send data from the JS to the C# functions..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653637/jquery-ajax-post-to-c-sharp

use this link

Comment: seams you will need to go through some articles or tutorials before going forward, or at least see some fast examples, start by google "jquery ajax with c#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using jQuery based on your tags.

**To send a GET request in jQuery:**

```
$.get("myUrl", function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

`data` contains the content of myUrl - if the content is json, it will be a [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject), if not it will be a string.

**To send a GET request with parameters in jQuery:**

```
$.get("myUrl", {"param1":"content","param2":"content"}, function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

**To send a POST request in jQuery:**

```
$.post("myUrl", {"param1":"content","param2":"content"}, function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand how to get the result of a specific function. I entered my page url (Default.aspx) , and the data returned is the html of the page itself.. i wonder how i can get the result of a function i have in the code behind this aspx page..