# How to call a controller Action passing id parameters from a modal partialView?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, action, partial-views, viewbag

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC5 project with a view containing partialViews. In it I show a Bootstrap modal that loads data from a record in context. I need the identifier of this record to be passed as a parameter in an `<a>` tag that redirects to another action of the same Controller.

I tried to mount it like this:

```html
<a asp-controller="Controller" asp-action="Action" asp-route="@ViewBag.Value" class="btn btn-default">
  <i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i> 
  Button
</a>
```

However it doesn't work, it doesn't recognize the ViewBag.

I also tried with Onclick script, like this, but the `id` parameter arrives as null.

```
$('#idA').attr('action', '/Controller/Action/'@ViewBag.id);
```

Has anyone done something like this or can help me?

Comment: Just to make sure whether id is available in modal, are you able to display (like a label or some element) idA with viewBag.id on the modal dialog  ?

Comment: The idA is already displayed in the modal currently with a span

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp-route-id

```
<a asp-controller="Controller" asp-action="Action" asp-route="@ViewBag.Value" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.id" class="btn btn-default">
  <i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i> 
  Button
</a>
```

Comment: I tried this way and the page doesn't even load. Shows this error: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: Cannot determine the 'href' attribute for <a>. The Following attributes are mutually exclusive: asp-route asp-controller, asp-action, asp-page, asp-page-handler

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or jquery for getting the values and ajax to post to the controller, something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10653696/7687161

Answer (score 0):

You should  not combine asp-route="xx" and asp-controller="xx"
try with this:

```
<a asp-controller="Controller" asp-action="Action" asp-route-Id="@ViewBag.Id" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i>
    Button
</a>
```

[image]